# No overload for process_OutputDataReceived matches delegate System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#

This error never occurred before. Here is my code;

```
        private Process process = null;
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != process)
        {
            process.Dispose();
        }

        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "world.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Here is what I'm getting an error on:

```
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
```

That above is fine until I wrote out;

```
    private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Help would be appreciated. Don't know how this can be anymore specific than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is that you have a namespace conflict (i.e. there are other classes in your environment that match the names of the classes being used).

Try using explicit namespace declaration:

```
    process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

    private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! Remember, it is very helpful on this site to click the checkbox and up arrow next to any answer that solved or help you solve your question so that future visitors to the question know which answer helped you out.